# Disabled <input> that allows text selection?

Tags: html

Is it possible for a disabled `<input>` tag to support text selection?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could use the ReadOnly attribute.

Comment: Probably the only fix. Note that this is not identical to the `disabled` attribute - the value in the field will be submitted to the receiving script

Comment: Also notice that readonly field can be modified by a script for example. Think about autocomplete scripts for example: as the field gets focus, the script can show other values that can be chosen. So be careful.

Comment: It's not working, you can still select text in the input with `readonly` attribute

Comment: @KimchiMan - This question was asked and answered more than 6 years ago. Yes, you can still select the text.  That's the _point_.  That was _what the OP asked for_.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Oh sorry - my bad

Answer (score 20):

Based on [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#disabled), it looks like no:

> - Disabled controls do not receive focus.
> - Disabled controls are skipped in tabbing navigation.
> - Disabled controls cannot be successful.

Are you able to use the `readonly` attribute instead?

*(Wow, "4 new answers have been posted"... I think the spec link is helpful, at least.)*

Answer (score 3):

This will depend heavily on the browser. It works fine for me in Chrome and IE8: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6Rry/)

Firefox (3.6) seems to be the one browser that doesn't support it. I don't think you can do anything about that.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use a `readonly` input and style it with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

readonly="readonly" is your answer

you can remove border in CSS or directly in styles, when you "blocked" this field and it will look like regular text, bring back the look when "unblocked"...

Comment: This is wrong, readonly sends the field with the form, disabled doesn't.