# Button to copy text copies page source instead

Tags: javascript

Not much to add. This button has worked before. it would copy the code within it. Now whenever it is pressed the `value="#code"` is displayed to the user but not copied?

```html
<input type="text" class="buttontxt" value="#Code" id="code" disabled>
<button class="button copy" onclick="myFunction()">Copy Code</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("code");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the code: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
```

No idea why this has suddenly happened. It's broken in all of the browsers & on mobile. Would appreciate if someone could make this work again because I'm clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Some commands need a value to be completed.

> document.execCommand(command, showUI, value)

You need to pass the value.

Comment: `Some commands need a value to be completed`…however, `copy` isn't one of them. You can prove this anecdotally: try running `document.execCommand('copy', false, 'test')`—nothing copies. `document.execCommand('copy')` only works on text that has been selected within the DOM—values cannot be passed directly to the clipboard via the JS `aValueArgument` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to lie in the fact that your `input` element is `disabled`. See [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726715/disabled-input-that-allows-text-selection) for more explanation, but you should change the `disabled` attribute to `readonly` so that your `select()` call can actually select the text. Right now, since the text is never selected, there is nothing to copy when `document.execCommand("copy")` is called, but since the text is accessible to JS, it shows up in the `alert` dialog as expected—hence the behavioral discrepancy. Here's a working version of your code:

```html
<input type="text" class="buttontxt" value="#Code" id="code" readonly>
<button class="button copy" onclick="myFunction()">Copy Code</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("code");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the code: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Fixed it, thank you. I've hidden the text (made it white) any ideas on how to disable the border for just this one text element?

Comment: @phphelpplease To hide the border, use the CSS `#code { border: none; }`. If you're looking to hide the `input` altogether, though, you might be better off using one of the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593297/using-execcommand-javascript-to-copy-hidden-text-to-clipboard) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561771/copy-text-from-a-hidden-control-using-javascript).